# Linux GPIO persistent output

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux, gpio

In the deprecated sysfs interface, writing a value to an output pin would persist. I'm not sure how to do this with the new interface.

This is how I'm writing a value for 2 seconds:

```c
// get linehandle
ret = ioctl(fd, GPIO_GET_LINEHANDLE_IOCTL, &request);
if (ret < 0) {
  return -1;
}
// write
ret = ioctl(request.fd, GPIOHANDLE_SET_LINE_VALUES_IOCTL, &data);
if (ret < 0) {
  close(request.fd);
  return -1;
}

usleep(2000000);
close(request.fd);
```

In order for this to persist, I could launch a thread... but would I leave this request fd open? And when I want to lower the pin, do I just close this request fd?

I was expecting there to be an easier way to keep gpio pins high in the new interface since it was so simple with sysfs. However, I am testing with gpio-mockup so there is a chance something isn't working quite right.

Comment: **1.** Yes, you have to keep the file descriptor (or actually the _line handle_) open as long as you want to keep control over the GPIO line. **2.** No, you must not rely on the driver behaviour which may or may not follow your expectations. I.o.w. to put it low (or rather _non-active_, because GPIO library / kernel operates in logical and not physical states) you must do it explicitly in your code. **3.** Use `gpio-sim` as `gpio-mockup` also deprecated.

Comment: @0andriy thanks!! Any good resources for setting up  gpio-sim? I’m not familiar with configfs

Comment: Sure, https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/gpio/gpio-sim.html.

Comment: @0andriy looking at gpio.h I am even more confused, now seeing `v2` all over. And also read that only `gpio/driver.h` and `gpio/consumer.h` should be used... I am writing for a Beaglebone Black, so my question is, which version of this api would you recommend using? The team I'm on was using sysfs and I'm not sure if I should use v1 or v2 of the char device, stick with sysfs, or use gpiod.

Should I avoid gpiod? I have a feeling cross compiling will be a problem

Comment: It seems you are mixing in-kernel APIs with the user space ones. Just use `libgpiod` in the user space if you need to access GPIOs from user space.

Comment: @0andriy cannot use libgpiod since I need to cross compile for beagle bone. Same reason we have [this](https://github.com/badgerloop-software/sc1-main-io/blob/gtest-and-can/embedded/drivers/include/i2c-dev.h) file instead of `<linux/i2c-dev.h>`

Comment: I'm not sure how the issue with cross-compilation is related to use of the libraries. Maybe you need to fix that first?

Comment: @0andriy sure, I’m planning on using buildroot since I can run `make sdk` to get a cross compiler very easily. I’m pretty confused on what allows a cross compiler to be compatible. The beaglebone head dev wrote a post where he compiles with higher gcc than the target. I was running into glibc issues when I was trying. I want to use buildroot to be positive everything is under my control. Do you have any advice? Maybe this isn’t the place to ask all this sorry

Comment: Yes, Buildroot is a good choice since it solves all these issues for you. And it has all needed libraries in the distribution.